# MATLAB - load file whose filename is stored in a string

Tags: string, matlab-load

I am using MATLAB to process data from files. I am writing a program that takes input from the user and then locates the particular files in the directory graphing them. Files are named:

> {name}U{rate}

{name} is a string representing the name of the computer. {rate} is a number. Here is my code:

```
%# get user to input name and rate
NET_NAME = input('Enter the NET_NAME of the files: ', 's');
rate = input('Enter the rate of the files: ');

U = strcat(NET_NAME, 'U', rate)
load U;

Ux = U(:,1);
Uy = U(:,2);
```

There are currently two problems:

1. When I do the `strcat` with say 'hello', 'U', and rate is 50, U will store 'helloU2' - how can I get `strcat` to append {rate} properly?
2. The load line - how do I dereference U so load tries to load the string stored in U?

Many thanks!

Comment: 1. filename = sprintf("%s.%d", name, rate)<br/>
2. fdata = load(filename)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mikhail's comment above solves your immediate problem.

A more user-friendly way of selecting a file:

```
[fileName,filePath] = uigetfile('*', 'Select data file', '.');
if filePath==0, error('None selected!'); end
U = load( fullfile(filePath,fileName) );
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to using [SPRINTF](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/sprintf.html) like Mikhail suggested, you can also combine strings and numeric values by first converting the numeric values to strings using functions like [NUM2STR](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/num2str.html) and [INT2STR](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/int2str.html):

```
U = [NET_NAME 'U' int2str(rate)];
data = load(U);  %# Loads a .mat file with the name in U
```

One issue with the string in `U` is that the file has to be on the [MATLAB path](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/path.html) or in the current directory. Otherwise, the variable `NET_NAME` has to contain a full or partial path like this:

```
NET_NAME = 'C:\My Documents\MATLAB\name';  %# A complete path
NET_NAME = 'data\name';  %# data is a folder in the current directory
```

[Amro's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2303890/matlab-load-file-whose-filename-is-stored-in-a-string/2304189#2304189) of using [UIGETFILE](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/uigetfile.html) is ideal because it helps you to ensure you have a complete and correct path to the file.