# Loading filename stored in string and then plotting data

Tags: matlab, file-io, mat-file

I am attempting to create a script which asks the user for the filename of a txt file whose contents will later be plotted.

```
filename = input('What is the filename (without the extension) e.g. RCP6: ','s');
if isempty(filename)
    filename=input('What is the filename (without the extension) e.g. RCP6: ','s');
end

ext =  input('What is the filetype (extension) e.g. .txt: ','s');
if isempty(ext)
    ext=input('What is the filetype (extension) e.g. .txt: ','s');
end

filew = strcat(filename,ext)

load(filew)
A = filename
Y = A(:,1)
E = A(:,2)

plot(Y,E)
xlabel('calendar year')
ylabel('annual fossil carbon emissions (GtC)')
```

As written, the code correctly concatenates filename and ext, however, it does not appear that load (filew) correctly loads that file, since given a filename = RCP3PD for example, Y = R and E = C, instead of Y storing the first column of values from RCP3PD.txt?

Any Suggestions? I have seen other "load file from string" threads make reference to the sprintf() function - would that apply here?

Comment: why do you have `A = filename` after the LOAD call? Also what's inside your MAT-file? type the following: `whos -file myFile.mat` to see its content

Comment: also instead of requesting the input on the command line, consider using functions like [UIGETFILE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/uigetfile.html). See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2304189/97160) for an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you load the data you need to save it as something. So :

```
load(filew)
```

Should look like

```
data = load(filew);
```

Then to access your variables simply use:

```
A = data.A; % assume that data is a struct with a field named A
Y = A(:,1);
E = A(:,2);
```

*Other Thoughts*

You might consider changing the logic for typing a file name to something like this:

```
valid = 0;
while(valid==0)
  filename = input('What is the filename (without the extension) e.g. RCP6: ','s');
  ext =  input('What is the filetype (extension) e.g. .txt: ','s');
  if exist([filename, ext], 'file')
    valid = 1;
  end
end
```

Instead of checking to see if the filename is empty check to see if the user has provided a filename/extension pair that actually exist. If not then keep asking until they do.

If you want to get fancy you might use `uigetfile` instead of asking the user to type in a filename.  This presents the user with a file picker window and this way you know that they have picked a valid file. Additionally it allows you to filter what files the user can chose.